# Changing Java on my Mac to 8

Tags: macos, java

I'm about to get back into java programming, so I downloaded the latest version of Java, Java 8 update 40.

Now, my MacBook has seen better days, and who knows how many version of Java is in it. At first everything went fine, with `java -version` giving me the right one (1.8).

Then I tried running Spring Tool Suite, which was pointing to the wrong jvm, that of 7, and jvm 8 isn't listed anywhere.

After trying out a lot of ln's, a lot of rm's, etc., etc, I tried to install Java for OSx 2014-001.

Worst mistake so far, so I tried re-installing jre-8u40-macosx-x64.dmg.

Didn't help one bit. Now even `java -version` reads:

```
java version "1.7.0_71"  
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14)  
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode)
```

While `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` says:

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
    1.7.0_71, x86_64:   "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_65-b14-466.1, x86_64: "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_65-b14-466.1, i386:   "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

All while the Java control panel displays:

[image]

So, which screw do I hammer in with my wrench this time?

Comment: is http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/143717/trouble-updating-to-java-8-jdk any use ?

Comment: @Tetsujin, unfortunately, no. My .bash_profile contains nothing but a php line, `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` has nothing but `jdk1.7.0_71.jdk`, typing in `/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8` returns `Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.8".
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home`.

Comment: Install the JDK rather than the JRE to get full Java 8 on OS X

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to install the JDK rather than just the JRE to get full Java support on OS X.

The official Oracle download site is http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html Click on 'Java Platform (JDK)' and download 'Mac OS X x64'

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add a link to where to get it.  Thanks.

Comment: @fixer1234 Added download location